# Conversion of date and time to unix timestamp - kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, unix-timestamp

In *timestamp* variable, I want to get the timestampt value with the current hour, minute and second. The currentDataTime gives me the time in this format: **2020-08-28 17:18:02**.
Currently, the *timestamp* variable returns me **1598645882634** (the last 3 numbers are the miliseconds) but when I convert it in a online conversor to a Human readable format, it gives me **08/28/2020 @ 8:18pm (UTC)**. The only one problem is the hour and minute tha is 3 hours different because of my zone. How can I convert the date AND **time** to timestamp?

```
object DateTime {
    val currentDataTime: String
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
        get() {
            val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
            return dateFormat.format(Date())
        }

    val timestamp: String
        get(){
            val formatter: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
            val date = formatter.parse(currentDataTime) as Date
            return date.time.toString().dropLast(3) //it is returning 
    }
}
```

Comment: That's correct result in my opinion. Unix time is always in UTC, it doesn't have information about timezones. What result do you expect?

Comment: @sergeyglotov, my only one problema is that the number returned as timestamp is 3hours ahead

Comment: @SergeyGlotov if you put **2020-08-28 17:18:02** in an online converter to timestamp, you will get a different number than **1598645882.634**

Comment: If **I** put this in an online converter, I'll get yet another result different from your. Keyword: UTC. "2020-08-28 17:18:02" in your timezone is "20:18:02" in UTC. And "2020-08-28 20:18:02" (UTC) is 1598645882

Comment: `$ date -jur 1598645882` gives `Fri Aug 28 20:18:02 UTC 2020`

Comment: `$ date -jr 1598645882` gives `Fri Aug 28 23:18:02 MSK 2020`. It's still the same timestamp, but in my timezone (UTC+3).

Answer (score 3):

A [**Unix timestamp**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is defined to be ([almost](https://lwn.net/Articles/648313/)) UTC. It carries no timezone information so it cannot be shifted according to a timezone difference without everything based on it falling apart. (If you'd like to hardwire it anyway, according to your example just add your timezone difference in milliseconds. But read on first.)

**Localized time** can only be interpreted consistently as long as the proper timezone is attached. It jumps back and forth whenever daylight-savings time starts or ends. If that's not complicated enough, the rules for daylight-savings time may change at any time (and do so around the globe).

Your online converter apparently just took a UTC-based timestamp and displayed it according to your local timezone.

To handle localized date and time values, use the multiplatform date/time library [kotlinx-datetime](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-datetime). In the README section [Converting an instant to local date and time components](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-datetime#converting-an-instant-to-local-date-and-time-components) you'll find this example:

```kotlin
val currentMoment: Instant = Clock.System.now()
val datetimeInUtc: LocalDateTime = currentMoment.toLocalDateTime(TimeZone.UTC)
val datetimeInSystemZone: LocalDateTime = currentMoment.toLocalDateTime(TimeZone.currentSystemDefault())
```

There you'll also find elaborate explanations on which type of date and time to use in which scenario.

Comment: Hi, these pieces of code you pass me, didn't are accepted by android studio, some functions aren't recognized by it.

Comment: my problem is only about the 3 hours ahead in timestamp result I get when convert the datetime

Comment: Regarding the above code, did you check the section [Using in your projects](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-datetime#using-in-your-projects) of the `kotlinx-datetime` README? You need to add its dependency.

Comment: I think kotlin-datetime looks very promising and intuitive.
Am I missing something, or would "converting to a native date and using native dateformatter" (e.g. Date/NSDate for iOS and java.LocaldateTime for android) be the best practice if I have to display an Instant somewhere to the user?

Comment: Currently, kotlinx-datetime has limited abilities to convert to (or from) a string – see [issue #58](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-datetime/issues/58). So yes, using the native functions for string conversions is definitely an option.